# powershell $ie.Document.getElementById("username").value="my username " error

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I want to automate a login form using powershell:

```
<form method="post" class="login-form" name="loginForm" action="/Service/WebObjects/Service.woa/wo/0.15.7.3.1">
<label>Username</label>
<input maxlength="128" style="width: 240px;" type="text" name="username" />
<label>Password</label>
<input maxlength="64" style="width: 240px;" type="password" name="password" />
<input class="login-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rememberCheckBox" value="15.7.3.1.15" />
<label class="login-check-label" for="flag_stay_logged_in">Remember login</label><br/>
<noscript>
You need a JavaScript enabled browser to use this application.
</noscript>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div class="buttonBar"><input alt="Login" class="button" type="submit" value="Login" name="ButtonLogin" /></div>');
</script>
</form>

$ie=New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application  
$ie.visible=$true  
$ie.ParsedHtml
$ie.Navigate("https://livetime/Service/WebObjects/Service")  
while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}  

$ie.Document.getElementById("username").value="my username "  
$ie.Document.getElementById("password").value="my password " 
$ie.Document.getElementById('ButtonLogin').click()
```

After ran this script I get these errors:

```
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:7 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementById("username").value="mt username"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:8 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementById("password").value="my password "
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

The examples from internet I found show that this script should work.

Is there something that I can/should check (different/old version or settings)?

Comment: There are several faults in your HTML page but most important, if you want to do a `getElementById` you should obviously define an **id=**.
 I recomment you to simplify your HTML page to just:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" class="login-form" name="loginForm">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input maxlength="128" style="width: 240px;" type="text" id="username" name="username" />
  <label>Password</label>
  <input maxlength="64" style="width: 240px;" type="password" id="password" name="password" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: The above HTML page (in the comment) works for me. If you can't change the HTML page, concider to use `getElementsByTagName` (`input`) and enumerate them accordingly.

Comment: I'm not able to change the html code. More than this is part to a page html but I put here only the "submit by post part" The problem is why $ie.Document.getElementById("username").value="my username "  
$ie.Document.getElementById("password").value="my password " 
$ie.Document.getElementById('ButtonLogin').click()   does not work even all examples show that should work . I'm thinking that something is not enabled /installed , old version etc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no **id** defined for the elements you want to get (there is a **name** defined but this is not the same!). For the examples you referring to you, will see that there is also no **id** attributes defined.
This means you have to fetch the concerned elements another way, one possible way is to use **getElementsByTagName** to fetch the inputs and enumerate them accordingly:

```
$ie=New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application  
$ie.visible=$true  
$ie.ParsedHtml
$ie.Navigate("https://livetime/Service/WebObjects/Service")  
while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
$document = $ie.Document
$form =  $document.forms[0]
$inputs = $form.getElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "username"}).value = "my username"
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "Password"}).value = "my password"
```

I have confirmed this to work for my simplified test page (which has no id for the inputs defined either):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" class="login-form" name="loginForm">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input maxlength="128" style="width: 240px;" type="text" name="username" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input maxlength="64" style="width: 240px;" type="password" name="password" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you still can't get it to work with the specific webpage (which I can't access from here), I recommend you to build a simplified HTML page yourself and make this available through a (portable) webserver (e.g. http://www.usbwebserver.net). So that we are literally on the same page...

Comment: This worked for me! just to complete the whole process, add `($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "Login"}).click()` to login.